# Rectangle not moving on display PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

width = 500
height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Client")
clientNumber = 0
class Player():

    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color,win):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width 
        self.height = height 
        self.color = color 
        self.rect = (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)
        self.val = 3
        self.win = win

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.color, self.rect)

    def move(self):
        keyPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x = self.x - self.val
        if keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x = self.x + self.val
        if keyPressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y = self.y - self.val
        if keyPressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y = self.y + self.val

def refreshWindow(win,player):
    win.fill((255,255,255))
    player.draw()
    pygame.display.update()




def main():
    player = Player(50,50,100,100,(0,255,0),win)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
        player.move()
        refreshWindow(win,player)

main()
```

The code is updating self.x and self.y and key is being pressed, but the display is not changing the 
position of the rectangle. I am new to this and was learning from a tutorial. My code is the exact as that tutorial guide but its not working. Like only its not displaying the updated version. The rest is working fine, i printed statements to verify that the window object is the same and if key was pressed and if x and y coordinates were being changed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you have answered your question and fixed your issue I want to mention something. It is not a great idea to have your game object keep both a `self.rect` and separate `self.x`, `self.y`, `self.width`, `self.height` attributes as you are doing.

All those attributes are contained within the `rect` and keeping to separate versions of the same data just means that you have to be updating them both and is large potential for errors either because one or the other did not get updated, or because the state was checked before it got updated and so it contained an old value.

just use a Rect and access the x, y, width, height values as attributes in it like this `self.rect.x`, `self.rect.y`, `self.rect.width`, `self.rect.height`.

You should check the docs for Rect [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and see how much more useful it is than working with separate x,y,width, and height values. For example being able to manipulate it by the center, or being able to directly test the right edge without having to add the width, etc.

The exception with respect to keeping a separate `self.x` and `self.y` is if you are having issues related to angular movement where your velocity could be fractional and need floating point accuracy for the positions, since Rects keep int values. In that case you would keep adjust the `self.x += vel_x` and `self.y += vel_y` and then immediately assign the x,y to the rect `self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)` and then use the rect for  the rest. The x and y are just for the position accuracywhen you need fractional position adjustments, which does not apply here in your example.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you so much for this. I forgot I could access them from rect. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i fixed it. I was not changing the self.rect values. Although the tutorial didnt change it. Anyways, its working now.